# How to make selecteditem text red and bold on trigger (in combobox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selecteditem

I faced the problem: if I choose item from my combobox and its property .IsNotCorrect is true then make this selecteditem text red and bold and all other items in combobox are black. This is my attempt of doing this but nothing happens:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="REASON_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReason, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">                                                   
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>                                                        
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource lang_Common_SelectItem}"
                          IsEnabled="False"/>
            <CollectionContainer
                 Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaticReasons}}"/>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.IsNotCorrect, ElementName=REASON_ID}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. All items in drop down list, which `IsNotCorrect` bold and red or if __selected item__ `IsNotCorrect`, thenn all items in rop down list bold and red, or?

Comment: @Rekshino, if I choose item from my combobox and its property .IsNotCorrect is true then make THIS selecteditem text red and bold (all other items in combobox don't change)

Comment: Should the item be red in drop down list or do you mean a representation in text field?

Comment: @Rekshino, only representation in text field

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want, that all items in drop down list, which `IsNotCorrect` are bold and red, then remove your Style from displayed collection and put it to the `ComboBox.Resources`. The binding should also be adjusted:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsNotCorrect}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Resources>
```

If you want to change the representation in text field, then you have to modify the `ControlTemplate` of `ComboBox`.

- copy the default `ControlTemplate` of ComboBox see [ComboBox Styles
  and
  Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates)
  e.g. to the `Resources` of element, which contains your ComboBox.
- Change the `<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}"` to the `<Style
  x:Key="UsrDefinedStyle"`in the copied code.
- Find `TextBox` with name `PART_EditableTextBox` and **remove `Style="{x:Null}"`** in the copied code.
- Set style of your `ComboBox` to the `Style="{StaticResource UsrDefinedStyle}"`
- Put to the `Resources` of your `ComboBox`:

  ```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.IsNotCorrect, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
  ```

Comment: thanks a lot, seems that this is right answer but still can't apply it on my code (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295012/trying-to-override-textbox-for-combobox-styling-system-windows-markup-staticres)

Comment: Just try to execute __all steps__ I wrote.

Comment: I did all of them from make a default ControlTemplate to put a part of code in my combobox, pls see my another question, don't get what I missed

Comment: _" to put a part of code in my combobox"_ You had to copy all the code from MS page to the `Resources`. In your posted another question more than a half is missed.