# Trying to override textbox for combobox styling (System.windows.markup.staticresourceholder exception)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, selecteditem

I'm new in WPF and acccording to my previous question [How to make selecteditem text red and bold on trigger (in combobox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221731/how-to-make-selecteditem-text-red-and-bold-on-trigger-in-combobox?noredirect=1#comment106524599_60221731) I still have a problem with making my selecteditem (but not all combobox items) text red and bold in case when its IsNotCorrect property is true. If be more concrete I have **system.windows.markup.staticresourceholder** exception (it seems that all converters are declared, not sure of my new style declaring and the right order for it). These are the steps I have made:

- create style to override textbox for my combobox at the beginning of my xaml file:

  ```
  <Style x:Key="UserDefinedStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                      <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"          
             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             Margin="3,3,23,3"
             Focusable="True"
             Background="Transparent"
             Visibility="Hidden"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
      </Style>
  ```
- try to apply this style on my combobox (this part is inside of another style.

  ```
  <Border BorderBrush ="{Binding SelectedReason.IsNotCorrect, Converter={StaticResource DisablingBoolToColorConverter}}" BorderThickness="2">
  <ComboBox x:Name="REASON_ID" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedReason, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style"{DynamicResource UserDefinedStyle}">
       <ComboBox.ItemsSource>                                                          
            <CompositeCollection>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{DynamicResource lang_Common_SelectItem}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource StaticReasons}}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="Part_EditableTextBox">
                   <TextBox.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
                          <Style.Triggers>
                             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.IsNotCorrect, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
                                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                             </DataTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                       </Style>
                   <TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
           </CompositeCollection>
      </ComboBox.ItemsSource>                                                    
  </ComboBox>                                                
  </Border>
  ```

Comment: I would guess that it has something to do with this: `Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"`. Is that resource defines somewhere ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, yes, I think you're right: when I add this <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" ...(and so on) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/combobox-styles-and-templates example in my code I don't have any mistake but my textbox disappeared at all